# DotNetOpenAuth service provider sample

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I am looking into the service provider example with the hope of converting it to a WebAPI solution (I want to use OAuth 1.0a with my own MVC 4 app as a service provider)

However one thing confuses me, the sample has a reliance on session state to keep a handle on the Pending auth token whilst the user authenticates. However does this not require the client app to always support cookies and pass them in the subsequent requests? Is that reasonable?